# How to decompile groovy class files?

Tags: java, groovy

I have some class files, that can't be decompile properly because contain groovy code.

Is there suitable decompiler exists?

Or can somebody help me do it manualy for a reward?

Comment: Resulting class file would have had undergone much transformation from .groovy.  You may get ".java" like code back, even that will be less readable

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two decompilers,

1. JAD
2. JD-GUI(For GUI)

This is a little big process, you can go through this article to understand more to [decompile Groovy class](http://michael.laffargue.fr/blog/2013/11/02/decompiling-groovy-made-classes/).

Comment: The problem is: your link is like 4, 6 years old. I have no idea what updates JD-GUI saw in that time (some, but probably not too many). In other words: there is a big chance that this simply doesnt work any more for current day groovy classes.

Comment: @GhostCat, I understood ur concern. I found that is better to suggest. If you have anything better than my suggestion, please do it. I feel doing something is better than doing nothing. Let them try with my answer if it didn't work will look for alternatives.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are a lot of problems that lack good answers.

Comment: The link is now dead but can be found in the WaybackMachine https://web.archive.org/web/20140414205924/http://michael.laffargue.fr/blog/2013/11/02/decompiling-groovy-made-classes/